# UPDATE table using php jquery ajax and in a MVC way

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a HTML table and Edit - Delete - Save images are associated with each row. Now I want to edit any cell and when I'll click on Save-image it will be displayed on the HTML table with updated values, as well as the associated table in the database will also be changed. I want to do this using Jquery Ajax and PHP but in MVC way. I have tried but somehow database changes are not happening, while HTML table is showing the updated values.

**Ajax Code:**

```
function Save()
{
  var par = $(this).parent().parent();
  var tdCid = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
  var tdCname = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
  var tdCtype = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
  var tdRegno = par.children("td:nth-child(5)");
  var tdFare = par.children("td:nth-child(6)");
  var tdNightfare = par.children("td:nth-child(7)");
  var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(8)");    
  var Cid = $("#tdCid").val();
  var Cname = $("#tdCname").val();
  var Ctype = $("#tdCtype").val();
  var Regno = $("#tdRegno").val();
  var Fare = $("#tdFare").val();
  var Nightfare = $("#tdNightfare").val();    
  $.ajax({    
    url:"cardetails.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{cid:Cid, name:Cname, cartype:Ctype, regno:Regno,fare:Fare, nfare:Nightfare},
    success: function(response){
      if(response==1){    
        alert('Data Inserted / Modified Successfully');
      }
      else
      {
        alert('Error !! Data Insertion / Modification Failed');
      }
    }
  })

  tdCid.html(tdCid.children("input[type=text]").val());
  tdCname.html(tdCname.children("input[type=text]").val());
  tdCtype.html(tdCtype.children("input[type=text]").val());
  tdRegno.html(tdRegno.children("input[type=text]").val());
  tdFare.html(tdFare.children("input[type=number]").val());
  tdNightfare.html(tdNightfare.children("input[type=number]").val());
  tdButtons.html("<img src='delete.png' class='btnDelete'/><img src='edit.png' class='btnEdit'/>");
  $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
  $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
};
```

**cardetails.php script:**

```
include('helper.php');

$car = new Admin;

$r=$car->update($_POST['cid'],$_POST['name'],$_POST['cartype'],$_POST['regno'],$_POST['fare'],$_POST['nfare']);

if($r==1)
  return 1;
else
  return 0;
```

**helper.php script:**

```
class Admin extends connection
{
  var $update;
  var $insert;
  var $delete;
  function update($id,$name,$typ,$rno,$fare,$ncharge)
  {
    $this->update=mysqli_query($this->con,"UPDATE cars SET cname='$name',ctype='$typ',regno='$rno',fare='$fare',nightcharge='$ncharge' WHERE cid='$id'") or die(mysqli_error($this->con));
    if($this->update)
    {
      return 1;
    }
  }
}
```

**the path and connection class and all the names and id included within the AJAX query, PHP script and database table has been cross-checked twice.**

Comment: Have you checked the SQL statement you're generating is definitely valid and contains the data you exepect? Are there any client- or server-side errors reported? Does the ajax call return a HTTP 200, or an error code? All this basic debugging info would be useful. P.S. your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Learn to use parameterised queries. It will also help you avoid any syntax errors in your queries.

Comment: The alert box in the else part of the response is actually coming as the output. No other errors. SQL query and field names I have already checked.

Comment: ok then, very obviously, is there definitely a cars record with the cid which matches your input $id? And is cid a varchar field, or an int? Because you're trying to match it to a varchar (by enclosing it in quote marks). I only ask because the most common scenario with an ID is for it to be numeric.

Comment: Yes sir, I checked and as I mentioned earlier too, names, id and all the paths and file names are in a right order. Still that 'else section' of the 'success' part of that Ajax code is executing.

Comment: You didn't answer my question about the data type of the cid field. Also, if `$this->update` is false, try fetching the result of `mysqli_error($this->con)` and returning that to the client in the response, or logging it somewhere to the server where you can check it. Then you can check if the SQL is working. At the moment it could be just failing silently. Another good test would be to log what the actual generated SQL looks like (i.e. the result of the string created by `"UPDATE cars SET cname='$name',ctype='$typ',regno='$rno',fare='$fare',nightcharge='$ncharge' WHERE cid='$id'"`)